# How do I assign a new value to the user defined type?

Tags: ocaml

I have this code where I'm trying to insert a card into a hand. If the hand is empty, I want the hand to hold the card being inserted and to point to the next empty hand. If the hand is not empty, I want to look at the next card in the hand. How do I assign Hand (c, Empty) to the empty hand once it is reached?

Thanks.

```
let rec insert c h = match h with
  | Empty -> Hand (c, Empty)
  | Hand (c', h') -> Hand (c', insert c h')
```

Right now I'm playing around with the code above. Here is an example of the output:

```
# let hand0:hand = Hand ((Ace, Spades), Hand ((King, Diamonds), Empty));;
val hand0 : hand = Hand ((Ace, Spades), Hand ((King, Diamonds), Empty))
# insert (Ten, Hearts) hand0;;
- : hand = Hand ((Ten, Hearts), Empty)
# hand0;;
- : hand = Hand ((Ace, Spades), Hand ((King, Diamonds), Empty))
```

Clearly, the contents of hand0 doesn't change. I really don't understand what I need to write to assign a new value to the hand's empty hand once it is reached.
In addition, I thought that the recursion would at least display the first part of the hand (where it's not empty), but that doesn't work either. I really don't see why?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had it right, I just wasn't calling the function properly. Way to waste a couple hours for no reason..

```
# let hand0:hand = Hand ((King, Spades), Empty);;
val hand0 : hand = Hand ((King, Spades), Empty)
# let hand0 = insert (Ace, Diamonds) hand0;;
val hand0 : hand = Hand ((King, Spades), Hand ((Ace, Diamonds), Empty))
```

Answer (score 1):

In OCaml, you cannot assign to a variable. Any variable. There is no syntax in the language to do it.

`let someVar = something` declares and initializes a *new* variable that is in scope in the body of the `let`. Once a variable is defined, its value cannot change.

In your "answer", you defined a variable in an outer scope with the name `hand0`, and then you defined *another* (completely separate) variable also named `hand0` in an inner scope, which hides the `hand0` from the outer scope. However, you should note that this does not affect the outer `hand0`. You might as well name it something different:

```
let hand0 = Hand ((King, Spades), Empty) in
let hand1 = insert (Ace, Diamonds) hand0 in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an assignment, so I feel I should just give a hint. Your second case says, in essence, that you want to throw away the card `c'`. You can see this because `c'` doesn't show up in the result. I think what you want to do is to keep `c'`, so you probably need to include a `Hand` that has `c'` in it in your result. I hope this helps.

Comment: The way I see it, I want to keep the c that I'm actually inserting. If the hand isn't empty, it has a card there already. I don't care what card it is. I just want to look at the hand that it's pointing to which is `h'` which is why I call `insert c h'`. My problem is that I think my declaration for the empty case is wrong because I get a syntax error. how do I assign `h = Hand (c, Empty)` once the `Empty` case is reached? This is my question. To add, the syntax error it gives me says `characters 2-3` which mean the `|` for my Empty case. What am I typing wrong?

Comment: I don't get how I'm supposed the modify the contents of my hand.

Comment: could you please take a look at my code again? i included examples of how it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at ocaml syntax for a while, but I'm quite sure you want something like this:

```
Add last
    let rec insert c h = match h with
        Empty -> Hand (c, Empty)
      | Hand (c', h') -> Hand (c', insert c h')

Add first is trivial
    let insert c h = Hand (c, h)
```